# namespace Root reference

Tags: asp.net, dll, root

The type or namespace name 'Root' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where can find dll for the namespace Root? like here: http://report.sourceforge.net/source/HelloWorld.cs

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty old library. But you can find the source code here and binaries:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/report/